# How to select all values from a select tag selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to select all the options under the 'select tag'. Not in a for loop but all of them together.

I know how to select one option only.

This is the image of the table:

[image]

Code sample:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Dear, please confirm what you want. select one or select all at a time. If you select one option only then you will follow this link:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = [please input here browser path]
driver.get('https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('custom-select'))
select.select_by_index(2)
```

***NOTE: I am really sorry that i did not understand your question correctly***

Comment: I want to select all at once

Answer (score 0):

Here is the option to select all. I have mentioned 3 methods of identifying options. you can use any one to do that.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver.get("https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/")

time.sleep(5)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='custom-select browser-default']"))

for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@class='custom-select browser-default']/option"):
    select.select_by_visible_text("One")
    select.select_by_index(2)
    select.select_by_value("3")
```

Comment: but I wanted it without the for loop